# IMAP Saves All Emails to "/var/mail/user"

Tags: email, imap

I've got the courier-imap-ssl package installed and running alongside sendmail on a Linux box. However, I'm having a problem. I've changed the mail directory using `MAILDIRPATH=/path/to/email/dir` in both the `imapd-ssl` and `imapd` files, and was sure to use `maildirmake /path/to/email/dir` to create the directory.

What's even weirder is that when I try to send an email to myself (using Thunderbird, which doesn't appear to have any problems), the email appears in my sent folder, but I never receive it. Instead of my sent email being sent to `/path/to/email/dir`, it get put in `/var/mail/user` instead. My email goes to the same place when sent from an external host as well.

I can't find anything with a Google search, and I don't know where to even begin on finding the solution to this on my own. Is there some kind of configuration or missing program I need to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After relentless searching, I found the solution to my problem. `sendmail` uses this thing called `procmail`, which needs to be configured with the appropriate email directory.

- To set the email directory of an individual user, create `rw-r--r-- user:user /home/user/.procmailrc` that contains:

  ```
  :0
  /user-specific/email/dir
  ```
- To set a global email directory, create `rw-r--r-- root:root /etc/procmailrc` and add to it:

  ```
  DEFAULT=/new/email/dir
  ```